# How to test if Future is complete without race?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent

I'm tracking execution of a task with standard `Future` object. There are the following valid states of that task (as I see in Guava code of `AbstractFuture` class):

- *Running*;
- *Completing*;
- *Completed* successfully or with exception;
- *Cancelled*;
- *Interrupted*.

`Future.isDone()` returns `true` if and only if the state is *completed*, *cancelled* or *interrupted*. `Future.isCancelled()` returns `true` if and only if the state is either *interrupted* or *cancelled*.

Ok, but I need to check if the task is *completed*. There is an obvious way to do this:

```
boolean isCompleted = future.isDone() && !future.isCancelled();
```

Unfortunatelly, a nasty concurrency bug hides there.

1. Thread #1 invokes `future.isCancelled()`. The result is `false`, because the task is still in progress.
2. Thread #2 cancels the task calling `future.cancel()`.
3. Thread #1 invokes `future.isDone()`. The result is `true` now.
4. Evaluation of expression above yields `true`, and it's incorrect answer.

How to avoid this issue?

Comment: I didn't understand your comment about speculative optimizer in the other answer. Can you explain? How does that re-arrange the statement in the `&&`? (Is that even what you're hinting at?)

Comment: Does it really happen? I see that javadoc of `isDone()` doesn't guarantee `happens-before` for `isDone()`, but both `FutureTask` and Guava's `AbstractTask` are implemented in such a way that guarantees it.

Comment: Isn't the short circuiting of the `&&` operator sufficient to ensure that?

Comment: @DavidConrad: No, as long as happens-before relationship between `cancel()` and `isDone()` is not guaranteed. There is no such guarantee in javadoc.

Comment: @axtavt I believe that is what I was missing too, thanks.

Comment: `future.isCancelled()` can be pre-evaluated speculativelly with result caching. Speculative optimizer can do such tricks. He thinks that `isCancelled()` and `isDone()` calling are commutative, because he sees that no one can detect an actual calling order.

Comment: @const.grigoryev: I don't think so, because short-circuiting behavior of `&&` is strictly guaranteed by the JLS. The only reason why things may theoretically go wrong is memory visibility.

Comment: Can you try google's `ListenableFuture` which allows to call a listener when `Future` is completed?

Comment: @VictorSorokin `ListenableFuture` will launch listeners after task cancellation, as well as after normal termination

Comment: you can place your check `isDone() && !isCancelled()` inside a listener -- since `Future` is completed its' status won't change and you get proper visibility inside listener, so result will be correct.

Comment: Hi @const-grigoryev, why Thread#1 will execute the "future.isCancelled()" first ?  it will execute future.isDone first right ?

Answer (score 3):

You can try calling [`get(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#get%28long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) with an extremely short timeout. If it returns a value, it was completed. If you get a `TimeoutException`, it wasn't. If you get any other of the possible exceptions, it was either cancelled, failed, or was interrupted.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that the given solution is safe and that the worry for concurrency bugs is unfounded.

These are my three arguments:

1. Although not explicitly stated in the documentation `Future` I believe that it contrary to the spirit of the design of the class to allow such re-orderings as the one described in the question text.
2. None of the most popular implementations, `FutureTask`, `CompletableFuture` and Guava's `AbstractFuture` have the risk this re-ordering.
3. The [Javadoc of `Future`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) states the following:

   > Memory consistency effects: Actions taken by the asynchronous computation
   > *happen-before* actions following the corresponding `Future.get()` in another thread.

   I believe that it is resonable to assume that this applies not only the actions taken be by the asynchronous computation, but also to actions such as state transitions. This happens-before relationship forbids the problematic re-ordering

Conclusion: I believe that it is a documentation bug in `Future` that this is not explicitly stated.

#### Reason why popular implementation do not risk this re-ordering

The given solution is this:

```
boolean isCompleted = future.isDone() && !future.isCancelled();
```

In both `FutureTask`, `CompletableFuture` and Guava's `AbstractFuture` these operations involve reading an internal volatile `state` field. This `state` field is also written in every state transition. This forbids re-ordering of those operations.

The [Java Memory Model FAQ](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Epugh/java/memoryModel/jsr-133-faq.html) states this:

> - Each action in a thread happens before every action in that thread that comes later in the program's order.
> - A write to a volatile field happens before every subsequent read of that same volatile.

This implies that if `isDone` sees the value of the state *Completed* then there is a happens-before relationship between the write action of the state and the read action in `isDone` and `isCancelled`, by the second cited bullet in JMM FAQ.

There is also  a happens-before relationship between the call to `isDone` and the call to `isCancelled`, by the first cited bullet in JMM FAQ.

Hence the re-ordering between step 1. and step 3. in the question text is not possible.

The question poster worries that values are "pre-evaluated speculativelly with result caching". That kind of things can only be observable in the context of writes and reads from concurrent threads that are not ordered by `volatile`, `synchronized` or other mechanisms.